# Override auto generated css

Tags: css, angular, material-design

```
<app>
  <md-sidenav-layout>
     <md-sidenav></md-sidenav>     
  </md-sidenav-layout>
</app>
```

I am using the [Material Design sidebar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular2-material/sidenav) and it automatically generates an md-content tag with the following css.

```
[_nghost-gfi-10] > md-content {
    position: relative;
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   display: block;
   height: 100%;
   overflow: auto;
```

I want to change the overflow tag into hidden. Is it possible to override this property in css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that simply by adding CSS rule for md-content in a custom stylesheet. Material stylesheets are always loaded first so rules in custom stylesheets override MD rules.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In this case I am not sure how to override it because the first part is not always the same e.g. sometimes it is [_nghost-gfi-10] and another time it is [_nghost-mcq-10] . Can I override the css without specifying the first part of the css?